# Are $\sigma$ algebras of multiple coin tosses subsets?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If we consider the $\sigma$-algebra of a single coin toss, it is denoted by $\Delta_1=\{\{\},\{H\},\{T\},\{H,T\}\}$.

Similarly for a two coin toss it would be $\Delta_2=\{\{\},\{HH\},\{TT\},........,\{HH,HT,TT,TH\}\}$.

Then can it be said that $\Delta_1 \subset \Delta_2$?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, try to solve the problem before writing about it here.

Comment: A property which is somewhat similar to what you're talking about is that if $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, then $\sigma(X)\subseteq\sigma(X, Y)$. In your case $\sigma(X)$ would be $\{\{HH, HT\}, \{TH, TT\}, \emptyset, \Omega\}$, which is in some sense isomorphic to $\{\{H\}, \{T\}, \emptyset, \Omega\}$.

Comment: But isn't this supposed to be a general property as I see from this link: https://nptel.ac.in/courses/108106083/lecture8_Infinite%20Coin%20Toss.pdf

Comment: @Sumit it depends on the question how you construct the $\sigma$-algebra of events. It can be done  is such a way that $\Delta_1\subset\Delta_2$, but in your question you did not do that.

Comment: @drhab could you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly not. $\{H\}\in\Delta_1,\{H\}\notin\Delta_2 $

**EDIT**

In answer to the OP's question, $\mathscr F_n$ is the collection of subsets of all sequences of tosses, where membership can be decided on the basis of the first $n$ tosses.  For example, members of $\mathscr F_1$ include the set of sequences that start with heads, the set of sequences that start with tails and so on.  Clearly, if membership can be decided on the basis of the first toss, then it can be decided on the basis of the first two tosses.  The set of sequences that start with two heads is a subset of the set of sequences that start with one head.

Not every sequence belongs to $\mathscr F_n$ for some $n.$  Consider for example, the set of sequences with only finitely many heads., or the set of sequences where the cumulative number of tails is always greater than the cumulative number of heads.

Comment: Agreed, but given a $\sigma$ algebra on $\omega=\{H,T\}^{\inf}$, if $\Delta$ is the collection of subsets of $\omega$, then there is a property that $\Delta_{n}\subset \Delta_{n+1}$. What am I interpreting incorrectly?

Comment: @Sumit, where did you find that property?

Comment: In https://nptel.ac.in/courses/108106083/lecture8_Infinite%20Coin%20Toss.pdf

Comment: You misunderstand $\mathcal F_n$. Start with an easy case; look at $\mathcal F_2$, following the definition in that link.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not, outcome $\{H\}$ is not in $\Delta _2$.

Answer (score 1):

Example on request (see comments on question).

Going for $2$ tosses we can take as sample space the set $\Omega=\{HH,HT,TH,TT\}$ and as $\sigma$-algebra the collection $\Delta_2=\wp(\Omega)$.

In this model we focus on the **first** toss.

It induces the following sub-$\sigma$-algebra: $$\Delta_1=\{\varnothing,\{HH,HT\},\{TH,TT\},\Omega\}\subset\Delta_2$$

Note that e.g. $\{HH,HT\}$ is exactly the event that the first toss shows a head.